# create depency graph with javascript

Tags: javascript, graph, server

i want to make a graph which shows me how my servers are connected. I have as data
server1 connects to server2 x-times like:

```
Server1.foo.com;server2.foo.com;12
server1.foo.com;server3.foo.com;32
serverX.foo.com;serverY.foo.com;7
```

And now i want create a graph which makes something like

```
server2 <--12-- server1 -- 32 --> server3

serverY -- 7--> serverY
```

Is there any known Script/Software (free to use) which can do it dynamic?

Thanks you all for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which doesnt fit so good for big data, but with
https://rawgraphs.io/
You can use Cluster Dendrogram which do it this way.

If some1 has a better solution, it would be nice to post it.
Best regards